# Cant commit to github

Tags: git, github

I have a problem on how to commit my file to github.com repository using github Windows desktop. When I try, there's no publish to repository even though my first commit to master says "Commit Failed". [Here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJIdU.png)

[image: Here's my file to commit]

Comment: So what's in the debug log?

Comment: Can you try to do it from cmd? if it's success, then go back to GUI application.

Answer (score 1):

Check in `tools > settings` that your GitHub username and email is correctly set.

Then check in the logs that you don't have one of the files blocked by an handle (a process which keeps it open)

```
LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException:

Could not open 'SomePath\SomeProject.opensdf':

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```